# How to shorten a Data URI to pass it as a parameter to a printer?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, model-view-controller, zebra-printers

I have an ASP.Net MVC Web App. I have a page that I am using [JSBarcode](https://lindell.me/JsBarcode/) on to generate a barcode in the view. This barcode is generated as a long Data URI (`data:image/png;base64,xxx...`).

I am also using an [SDK](http://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/2-15/pc_net/) for a Zebra Printer that I am trying to print the barcode to. This SDK has a method that sends a print command to the printer but it uses the image's URL. With the barcode being generated as a data URI and not being an actual file anywhere, when I try to pass the URI to the printer I get the error:

> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

I think if the Data URI were shorter it would work, but I'm lost as to how to get past this.  The URI is always going to be crazy long and I'm looking for a way to shorten it so I can pass it to the printer.

If I can't shorten it is there a way I could store it as a temporary image that removes itself upon page refresh or something instead?  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.